# Configure an on-premise LDAP to Azure API manager?

Tags: azure-api-management

I could find that Azure AD can be configured to to Azure API manager.

My question is, is there a way to configure an on-premise LDAP to it?

A side question: can I configure SSO for the developer portal?

Comment: I think yes. But what is the version of your on-prem ADFS server ? Is it supported for openID ?. if it is ADFS - 2016 version.... then you can try same approcah as AAD on ADFS.

Comment: What part of APIM? Dev portal authentication (Identities) or linking aad server to an API?

Comment: My on-premise userstore is an OpenLDAP server. It has application developers.